# Loading large arrays from file, numpy slower than list appending. Where is the bottle neck?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, loading

I have a very large data .dat file that I am loading into a list, or numpy array.  The file contains columns of values with the last column being a multiplier of the number of times that value should be loaded into the array. Thus, when loading it, a second sub loop needs to be ran to take that into account.  This was done to make the total file size smaller, as they were getting well over 1Gb in some cases.

I did some testing with numpy pre allocated zeros arrays vs appending to a simply list and found the appending was faster.  Although, in numerous postings this should not be the case.  Where is the bottle neck?

```
    if True:
            startTime1 = time.clock()
            ## Numpy way to load up the data
            dataAry = np.zeros(TotalSamples)
            multiColAry = np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=2,                           usecols=(columNum,lastColLoc))
            latestLoc = 0               
            for i in range(0,multiColAry.shape[0]):
                curData = multiColAry[i][0]
                timesBeenHere = int(multiColAry[i][2])
                for j in range(0,timesBeenHere):
                    dataAry[latestLoc] = curData                        
                    latestLoc+=1
            endTime1 = time.clock()
            totalTime = (endTime1-startTime1) # in seconds
            totalTimeString = timeString(totalTime)

        if True:
            #Old string parsing directly version
            startTime1 = time.clock()
            totalAccepted = 0
            f = open(filename,'r')
            dataAry = []
            line = 'asdf'
            while line!='':
                line = f.readline()
                if line!='':
                    dataLineCols = line.split()
                    dataValue = float(dataLineCols[columNum])
                    timesBeenHere = float(dataLineCols[-1])
                    for j in range(0,int(timesBeenHere)):
                        totalAccepted+=1
                        dataAry.append(dataValue)

            f.close()
            endTime1 = time.clock()
            totalTime = (endTime1-startTime1) # in seconds
            totalTimeString = timeString(totalTime)
```

Thanks for any comments/suggestions.

Comment: did you try: `dataAry[latestLoc:latestLoc+timesBeenHere] = curData` instead of assigning the elements one by one? Notoriously `numpy` arrays are *slow* when doing operations on a per element basis. (The same can be done with the "list-appending" approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can replace your for loop with `numpy.repeat(multiColAry[:, 0], multiColAry[:, 2])`, that should make a pretty big difference.

Also, numpy arrays are generally index `array[i, j, k]` instead of `array[i][j][k]`, in this case the results should be the same but in some cases the latter will actually give you the wrong result. In either case the former should be faster.

Lastly element-wise operations and for-loops are discouraged when programming with numpy. Instead array-wise, or "vectorized", code is encouraged. In this paradigm you express the program as operations of arrays instead of operations on their elements. Numpy is optimized for this kind of programing. I know that this is unfamiliar for people coming over from lower level languages like C or Java, but it's similar to other scientific programing languages like Matlab or IDL.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I will keep them in mind as I try to increase my understanding and capabilities with numpy.  My future PhD work will require efficient code and those suggestions will surely come in handy if I end up writing that software in Python.

Answer (score 3):

In allocating a large zero array you need to clear a lot of memory, so if you allocate a large enough array with np.zeros, it may well start paging and will certainly clear your processor cache within that call alone. Allocating the array using [`ndarray(shape=(TotalSamples))`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html#numpy.ndarray) argument does not initialize it.

Secondly, the first version of the code keeps track of data the second one discards on the fly. The input file is clearly a text table of numbers, and the first implementation reads columns 0 and 2 while the second reads columns columnNum and -1. This indicates at least one column that the first version keeps in memory as long as multiColAry exists, while the second discards it as it moves on to the next line. You can avoid this using [`loadtxt(filename, usecols=(0,2))`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt).

Incidentally, did you know that [files are iterable](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.next)? Your tricky combination using `f.readline()` and empty string tests can be replaced with `for line in f:` (and [strings are false when empty](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), so you don't need to compare against the empty string).

Also, while using numpy, it is often a good idea not to write inner loops like `for j in range(0,timesBeenHere):` in Python. It could be restructured using `dataAry[latestLoc:latestLoc+timesBeenHere].fill(curData)` or `dataAry.append(multiEntries)`. Creating multiEntries is a chapter in itself, with possibilities like `np.ones(timesBeenHere)*dataValue` (traditional but costly if it doesn't fit in cache) or `np.linspace(dataValue,dataValue,timesBeenHere)`. Also see [ndarray.put()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html#numpy.put).

... I didn't even notice until now that the second version builds a list, not an array. Which brings to mind the question of how the data is later used. For now, I'll just assume it's converted to a numpy array in unseen code.

In the end, I am guessing something like this would probably be most convenient:

```
dataAry = np.empty(TotalSamples)
i=0
for line in open(filename):
  words=line.split()
  repeats=int(words[2])
  value=float(words[0])
  np.copyto(dataAry[i:i+repeats],value)
  i+=repeats
```

There's bound to be some way to use numpy to calculate the indices too, but I don't know which is more costly of parsing manually like this and loading the full table (well, the interesting columns) using loadtxt.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. 
As I have numpy 1.6, I instead use dataAry[i:i+timesBeenHere]=dataValue.
Two versions of the updated loops were made, one with a dataAry = [None]*TotalSamples and another with dataAry = np.empty(TotalSamples).  Both result in similar speeds, with the numpy one commonly taking about 5% longer.  For the time being, I will stick to the first, non-numpy one, as it was commonly a few seconds faster. 
Yes, after loading up the list, it is converted to a numpy array using np.sort() and a number of steps are performed after that including producing a histogram.

Comment: You decode an RLE encoded vector, then make a histogram from that? Sounds rather roundabout, as the histogram is binning of the data in the RLE list, and sorting it is a lot cheaper in that form as well.

Comment: The data is stored in a .dat file, not sure if that means it results in an RLE encoded vector as I don't know that is.  I load it into memory to sort it to let me easily calculate the median and confidence levels for the histogram.  Loading currently takes about 1min, sorting and finding the confidence levels takes around 30sec and plotting takes about 8sec.  So, If there is a much faster way to get that all done, I am interested.

Comment: RLE is run length encoding, the type of compression this question is about expanding. I'm not sure about confidence levels off the top of my head, but calculating medians and histograms is more efficiently done directly from this compression than from the expanded version. It's simply fewer entries to process.